# Проблема с @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, mvc, spring-mvc, аннотации

Есть код:

```
package com.example.sweater3;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

_

```
package com.example.sweater3.domain;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Message {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String text;
    private String tag;

    public Message() {
    }

    public Message(String text, String tag) {
        this.text = text;
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public void setTag(String tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }
}
```

_

```
package com.example.sweater3;

import com.example.sweater3.repos.MessageRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import java.util.Map;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @Autowired
    private MessageRepo messageRepo;
}
```

__

```
import com.example.sweater3.domain.Message;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface MessageRepo extends CrudRepository<Message, Long> {

    List<Message> findByTag(String tag);
}
```

pom.xml

```
 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mustache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

При запуске программы вылетает такая ошибка:

```
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.0.RELEASE)

2019-10-30 17:21:11.059  INFO 5064 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.sweater3.Application         : Starting Application on IlyaPC with PID 5064 (D:\TEST\5October\30\sweater3\target\classes started by Ilya in D:\TEST\5October\30\sweater3)
2019-10-30 17:21:11.063  INFO 5064 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.sweater3.Application         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-10-30 17:21:11.308  INFO 5064 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@7fa14664: startup date [Wed Oct 30 17:21:11 MSK 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-10-30 17:21:16.065  INFO 5064 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-10-30 17:21:16.111  INFO 5064 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-10-30 17:21:16.112  INFO 5064 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.28
2019-10-30 17:21:16.122  INFO 5064 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_221\bin;C:\Users\Илья\AppData\Roaming\npm;.]
2019-10-30 17:21:16.390  INFO 5064 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-10-30 17:21:16.390  INFO 5064 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5132 ms
2019-10-30 17:21:16.787  INFO 5064 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2019-10-30 17:21:16.800  INFO 5064 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2019-10-30 17:21:16.801  INFO 5064 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2019-10-30 17:21:16.801  INFO 5064 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2019-10-30 17:21:16.801  INFO 5064 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2019-10-30 17:21:16.885  WARN 5064 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'greetingController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'messageRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.sweater3.repos.MessageRepo' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2019-10-30 17:21:16.889  INFO 5064 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-10-30 17:21:16.926  INFO 5064 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-10-30 17:21:17.360 ERROR 5064 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field messageRepo in com.example.sweater3.GreetingController required a bean of type 'com.example.sweater3.repos.MessageRepo' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.sweater3.repos.MessageRepo' in your configuration.
```

Если убираю аннотацию @Autowired всё работает.

В чем проблема и как решить?

p.s. код максимально упрощенный, так как я убрал лишние куски, чтобы они не мешали читать код и не захламляли обзор.

UPD: Я допустил ошибку в копировании.

Вот ещё раз ошибка, которая вызвала вопрос:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-10-30 20:48:16.787 ERROR 2548 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field messageRepo in com.example.sweater3.GreetingController required a bean of type 'com.example.sweater3.repos.MessageRepo' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.sweater3.repos.MessageRepo' in your configuration.
```

И добавляю скрин:

Comment: может componentscan не видет ваш репозиторий, попробуйте сделать ребилд

Comment: Автор, Скинь скрин пекейджа

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо огромное всем кто заминусил мой вопрос и так и не помог!

Подсказали решение в другом источнике.

Нужно добавить аннотацию `@EnableJpaRepositories`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Обязательно добавить зависимость:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>       
</dependency>
```

И уже всё заработает, но тогда может появиться ошибка такого характера:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-10-30 21:46:01.970 ERROR 2716 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to auto-configure a DataSource: 'spring.datasource.url' is not specified and no embedded datasource could be auto-configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Значит мы на верном пути, остается подключить базу данных:

Возьму для пример postgresql:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

И конфигурации в resources/templates/application.properties (у каждого индивидуальные):

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sweater 
spring.datasource.username=postgres 
spring.datasource.password=root 
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

UPD: 
Аннотация `@EnableJpaRepositories`  необязатально.

Comment: Друг, я знаю по какому найду ты делаешь задание, если ты пожелаешь подключить mysql, то напиши, я пришлю тебе все нужные зависимости. Ибо мне самому помогали.

Comment: @Blacit да зависимости на mysql не проблема. а кинь мне свой ник в телеграмме

Comment: Он такой же. @Blacit

Comment: @EnableJpaRepositories аннотация не обязательна

Comment: @Санаев Согласен

Answer (score 1):

Всё просто, добавь в класс GreetingController вот эту строчку: `com.example.sweater3.repos.MessageRepo`

Если не поможет, то обрати внимание на ошибку, потому что у тебя Контроллер не видит репозиторий.

У тебя ошибка, потому что написано sweater, а нужно sweater3.

Comment: За что минусят на этом сайте?) За то, что человек после моего ответа уже отредактировал пост?

Comment: Возможно потому что это не решает проблему ^_^"

Comment: Справедливо :) Тогда только от автора комментарии надо ждать. Может, правда я что-то не так посоветовал.